# KeyListener randomly stops working. KeyBindings?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, key-bindings

I am making a game using RealTutsGML's tutorials, so if you have seen some of his old 2013 videos, you'll see where the outline of this code is coming from.

(By the way, I'm not new to Java, but I am fairly new to AWT and Swing and all that because I used to/still do sometimes code Minecraft Bukkit/Spigot plugins. I can understand a decent amount of the Java regular language/syntax, but AWT and Swing...)

Anyways, I am using a KeyAdapter to control the keys. However, it works at first and then just randomly stops working. I've debugged it and it seems that it's not the object in the game, it's the KeyAdapter. I've looked up some other solutions to this and people have said that it loses focus or something and that I should use KeyBindings instead. It's weird because the KeyListener RANDOMLY stops working for me.

Anyways, here is the code I am using:

```
Handler handler;

public KeyInput(Handler handler){
    this.handler = handler;

}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !tempObject.isJumping()){
                tempObject.setJumping(true);
                tempObject.setVelY(-10);
            }

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_Y){
                tempObject.setY(100);
            }

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                System.out.println("Pressed A");
                tempObject.setVelX(-5);
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                System.out.println("Pressed D");

                tempObject.setVelX(5);
            }

        }
    }

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {

        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player) {



            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                for (int velX = (int) tempObject.getVelX(); velX >= 0; velX--) {
                    tempObject.setVelX(velX);
                }
            }
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                for (int velX = (int) tempObject.getVelX(); velX <= 0; velX++) {
                    tempObject.setVelX(velX);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using a KeyAdapter to do that. Here is my initializing method in the main class:

```
private void init(){
    WIDTH = getWidth();
    HEIGHT = getHeight();
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.addObject(new Player(100, 100, handler, ObjectId.Player));
    handler.createTestLevel();

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));

}
```

The init method is being called before "this.requestFocusInWindow()"

I looked up some info on this and I saw KeyBindings as solutions to other people's problems. However, I think you have to add key bindings to JComponents, and I don't know how to get one of those in the game. new JComponent() doesn't work, and my JFrame is adding my main class (which is I believe acting as a Component, not JComponent).

If anyone can help, that would be great! Thanks!

EDIT #1:

I switched to KeyBindings! Here is the KeyInput class:

```
Handler handler;

public JComponent component;

public KeyInput(Handler handler, JComponent component){
    this.handler = handler;
    this.component = component;

    register();
}

public void register(){
    Actions actions = new Actions();

    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "pressSpace");
    component.getActionMap().put("pressSpace", actions.pressSpace());

    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "pressLeft");
    component.getActionMap().put("pressLeft", actions.pressLeft());
    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released A"), "releaseLeft");
    component.getActionMap().put("releaseLeft", actions.releaseXMovement());

    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "pressRight");
    component.getActionMap().put("pressRight", actions.pressRight());
    component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released D"), "releaseRight");
    component.getActionMap().put("releaseRight", actions.releaseXMovement());
}

public JComponent finish(){
    return component;
}


public class Actions{

    public Actions() { }

    public Action pressRight(){
        Action action = new AbstractAction(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                    GameObject temp = handler.object.get(i);
                    if (temp.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                        temp.setVelX(5);
                        System.out.println("pressed right debug");
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        return action;
    }

    public Action releaseXMovement(){
        Action action = new AbstractAction(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                    GameObject temp = handler.object.get(i);
                    if (temp.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                        temp.setVelX(0);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        return action;
    }
    public Action pressLeft(){
        Action action = new AbstractAction(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                    GameObject temp = handler.object.get(i);
                    if (temp.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                        temp.setVelX(-5);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        return action;
    }

    public Action pressSpace(){
        Action action = new AbstractAction(){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
                    GameObject temp = handler.object.get(i);
                    if (temp.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                        if (!temp.isJumping()){
                            temp.setJumping(true);
                            temp.setVelY(-10);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        return action;
    }

}
```

However, I am still having the same freezing problem. The debug messages don't get sent, so that means it doesn't have anything to do with my setVel methods. I don't know why the listener thing stops working...
(It works at first, but as I keep pressing the keys, it eventually stops).

Here's how I got the JComponent:

```
JComponent comp = (JComponent) frame.getContentPane();
    KeyInput input = new KeyInput(handler, comp);
    frame.add(input.finish());
```

Comment: If you need more specific help then as per my answer, you'll want to create and post a valid [mcve] as an edit to your current question. As always, the code should be posted as code-formatted text and not in a link.

Comment: See edit to answer regarding the bottom part of your question. Again, a MCVE would help immeasurably.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what do you mean not in a link? I don't have any links in my post.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "randomly" stop working. Rather it *likely* (we can't tell for sure without your valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) stops working when the listened to component no longer has focus. The choices are to create a kludge to force focus on the component (bad) or to use key bindings (good).

Regarding:

> I looked up some info on this and I saw KeyBindings as solutions to other people's problems. However, I think you have to add key bindings to JComponents, and I don't know how to get one of those in the game. new JComponent() doesn't work, and my JFrame is adding my main class (which is I believe acting as a Component, not JComponent).

Your GUI is replete with JComponents, starting with the JFrame's contentPane, and going on to any and every other GUI component that you to program -- remember that most **all** Swing components extend from JComponent, and these are valid components to add bindings to. Likely you'll add it to the main JPanel or JComponent of your GUI.

Comment: Alright! I using KeyBindings and edited the post above to show what I changed. However, I am STILL getting the freezing problem.

Comment: @Blockhead7360: I can't compile and run your code as posted. If you're still stuck, consider creating and posting a valid [mcve]. This is a *small* compilable and runnable program that is posted here in your question as code-formatted text (not in a link) and that demonstrates your problem for us. Good luck!